# kotlinFunction returns null if method is defined on an interface with a type parameter

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-reflect

A quick demo of a problem:

```kotlin
import kotlin.reflect.jvm.kotlinFunction

interface A<T> {
    fun aaa(t: T): String {
        return ""
    }
}

class B : A<String>

fun main() {
    println(B::class.java.methods[0].kotlinFunction) // returns null
}
```

Calling `kotlinFunction` on a method without type parameter returns an instance of `KFunction` as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is type erasure, that occurs in Java, but not in Kotlin:

Java:
`public java.lang.String B.aaa(java.lang.Object)`

Kotlin:
`public java.lang.String B.aaa(java.lang.String)`

https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/core/reflection.jvm/src/kotlin/reflect/jvm/ReflectJvmMapping.kt#L134

Note that it's just Kotlin compiler preserving some more information for reflection, types will be still erased by JVM at runtime, Kotlin or not.

If you need to access Kotlin method, do it directly:

```kotlin
println(B::class.functions.first())
```

Comment: Alexey, thanks for a quick reply. I'm experiencing this problem with spring framework, specifically with https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/kotlin-coroutines/src/main/kotlin/org/springframework/core/CoroutinesUtils.kt so I can't change the source code. I guess what I'm trying to clarify for myself is if it's a bug in kotlin or spring framework.

Comment: I honestly can't tell, because it's quite different from your original question. Looking at SpringFu code, I would suggest opening a bug on them, as the conversion does seem dangerous.